# How can I insert objects into an array in order of NSDate?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uiimageview, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that loads images that are used in a gallery for users profiles. The images are loaded in descending order using an "updatedPhotoAt" column in my DB.

The purpose of the "updatedPhotoAt" column is to allow users to set a default image. This column is only ever updated when a user swipes the image and taps the "default" button. The image whose "updatedPhotoAt" column has the most recent date is the default image.

Here is my code:

```
   func loadPhotoData() {
        pageViews = []
        pageImages = []
        let query = PFQuery(className: "UserImages")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
        query.addDescendingOrder("updatedPhotoAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: Array!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println("0 images found")
            } else {
                for object in objects as Array {
                    var imgDate = object["updatedPhotoAt"] as NSDate
                    println("1: \(imgDate)")

                    var imageFile = object["image"] as PFFile
                    var imgView = PFImageView()
                    imgView.file = imageFile
                    imgView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            //error alert
                        } else {
                            self.pageImages.append(image)
                            var imgDate = object["updatedPhotoAt"] as NSDate
                            println("2: \(imgDate)")
```

As you can see when I'm querying the db I'm making sure the results are returned descending order using the "updatedPhotoAt" column. In my block I print this columns date values so I can see if things are working correctly.

**Initially they are:**

1: 2015-01-30 12:15:54 +0000

1: 2015-01-22 10:23:00 +0000

1: 2015-01-14 10:19:00 +0000

**However in the imgView block they lose their order:**

2: 2015-01-22 10:23:00 +0000

2: 2015-01-14 10:19:00 +0000

2: 2015-01-30 12:15:54 +0000

This means that my default image only shows by chance and images are always show in random order in the users photo gallery (the gallery is a scroll view allowing the user to scroll horizontally through images. Default image should always be first in the list).

I see the problem is being caused by the imgView block. Is there a way I can preserve the order of the image?

Comment: The issue is `loadInBackground`, the images are not being received in the same order they are being requested. This is to be expected, you have to program around that.

Comment: I recommend to insert as it is. Then when you want to show contents of that array, just sort it using your right predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This challenge was knocking my confidence but with Wain's solution above and some patience I stuck at it all day and finally came up with a solution that seems to work very well.

**Code:**

```
func loadPhotoData() {
    pageViews = []
    pageImages = []
    let query = PFQuery(className: "UserImages")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
    query.addDescendingOrder("updatedPhotoAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: Array!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println("0 images found")
        } else {

            //index to assign to imgview tag to keep track of image in block
            var idx = -1

            var imageDictionary = Dictionary<Int, UIImage>()

            for object in objects as Array {

                idx++

                var imageFile = object["image"] as PFFile
                var imgView = PFImageView()
                imgView.tag = idx
                imgView.file = imageFile
                imgView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {

                    } else {

                        //store images in array for counting later
                        self.pageImages.append(image)

                        //store image index and image as dictionary value
                        imageDictionary[imgView.tag] = image

                    }

                    if objects.count == self.pageImages.count {

                        let sortedKeysAndValues = sorted(imageDictionary) { $0.0 < $1.0 }
                        println(sortedKeysAndValues)

                        for (k,v) in Array(sortedKeysAndValues).sorted({$0.0 < $1.0}) {
                            println("\(k):\(v)")

                            self.pageImages[k] = v
                        }
```

**Println log:**

```
[(0, <UIImage: 0x7fd5dac1df60>), (1, <UIImage: 0x7fd5d9455390>), (2, <UIImage: 0x7fd5da86a750>)]

0:<UIImage: 0x7fd5dac1df60>

1:<UIImage: 0x7fd5d9455390>

2:<UIImage: 0x7fd5da86a750>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect the `imgView.loadInBackground` asynchronous processes you start to all finish in the same order as they start.

Do something like filling all the slots you need to use in `pageImages` with `NSNull`, then, capture the index you should be populating with each image in the block and replace the item at that index rather than just appending.

Aside, you should probably limit the number of downloads you start at the same time. Try not to run more than 4 things at once.

Comment: I don't fully understand how to do this. I've add "var idx = -1" outside of the loop. Then "idx++ self.pageImages.append(NSNull())" inside the loop. I have 3 indexes representing the 3 images. 0, 1 and 2. I don't understand your suggestion to capture the index I should be populating with each image. Can you explain further please?

Comment: Just use the idx in the block to replace the NSNull entry